# Shifting order of rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make the last two rows of my dataframe `df` the first two of my dataframe with the previous first row becoming the 3rd row after the shift. Its because I just added the rows `[3,0.3232, 0, 0, 2,0.500]`, `[6,0.3232, 0, 0, 2,0.500]`. However, these get added to to the end of `df` and hence become the last two rows, when I want them to be the first two. I was just wondering how to do this.

```
df = df.T
df[0] = [3,0.3232, 0, 0, 2,0.500]
df[1] = [6,0.3232, 0, 0, 2,0.500]
df = df.T
df = df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just call [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) and pass the new desired order:

```
In [14]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c']})
df
Out[14]:
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
In [16]:

df.reindex([1,2,0])
Out[16]:
   a
1  b
2  c
0  a
```

**EDIT**

Another method would be to use [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) note that this returns a `np.array` so we have to explicitly select the columns from the df to overwrite them:

```
In [30]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'], 'b':np.arange(3)})
df

Out[30]:
   a  b
0  a  0
1  b  1
2  c  2

In [42]:    
df[df.columns] = np.roll(df, shift=-1, axis=0)
df

Out[42]:
   a  b
0  b  1
1  c  2
2  a  0
```

The `axis=0` param seems to be necessary otherwise the column order is not preserved:

```
In [44]:    
df[df.columns] = np.roll(df, shift=-1)
df

Out[44]:
   a  b
0  0  b
1  1  c
2  2  a
```

Comment: Thank You. Is there a better way to do this for large dataframes? I ask because my dataframe has 59 rows and the indices are all over the place.

Comment: You could take slices and concat them, depends how complicated this gets

Comment: I may not be understanding your comment, but the axis=0 is not about column order but rather doing a row shift vs column shift.

Comment: @JohnE I was a little surprised that the default param `axis=None` meant that it rolled along both axes that was what I was surprised by

Comment: Oh, thanks, I see now.  Apparently with axis=None, it flattens, shifts, and then puts it back to original shape.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the easiest solution is just to add the new rows to the beginning in the first place:

```
existing_rows = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(4,3) )
new_rows      = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(2,3) )

new_rows.append( existing_rows )

          0         1         2
0  0.406690 -0.699925  0.449278
1  1.729282  0.387896  0.652381
0  0.091711  1.634247  0.749282
1  1.354132 -0.180248 -1.880638
2 -0.151871 -1.266152  0.333071
3  1.351072 -0.421404 -0.951583
```

If you really want to switch rows you can do as EdChum suggests.  Another way is like this:

```
df.iloc[-2:].append( df.iloc[:-2] )
```

I think this is slightly simpler than `np.roll` as suggested by EdChum, but numpy is generally faster so I'd use `np.roll` if you care about speed.  (And doing some quick tests on 1,000x3 data suggests it is about 3x to 4x faster than `append`.)